# ListView in AppWidget 'exceeding' widget dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-appwidget

I have a `ListVie`w inside an `AppWidget`. Each row of the `ListView` has a custom layout, `AppWidget` specifies a `minHeight`, as required. The problem is that `ListView` exceeds the dimensions of the `AppWidget`, and some rows simply hang below the widget boundaries.

I have tried everything I could think of, fixing the height of `ListView`, using `match_parent` and/or `wrap_content` or rows and `ListView`, but I have not been able to fix this.

Has someone else faced this problem? How do I make the `ListView` fit inside the widget boundaries and scroll, instead of rows getting outside the boundary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have root-caused the issue, and I am to blame here, at least partly.

I am asked to use a custom background for the `ListView`, and the 9-patch I received had a shadow drawn below the 'content' background. Android used the whole png for drawing the background, lending an appearance of 'one row hanging off the content' appearance to the widget.

I verified this by using a solid color as background - it extends properly to cover entire `ListView`.

My learning:
1. The `minWidth` and `minHeight` attributes for the widget are exactly what they say; Android WILL give more space to the widget if it can. :)
2. You've specified "minimum" width, and your actual width is being determined by the width of a child `View`. Given that such a case could be common, setting the top-level layout `width` and `height` to `wrap_content` in the widget's main view seems a reasonable thing to do.